# tooltip sempre presente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código:

http://jsfiddle.net/56bv52us/

O que estou a tentar fazer é a mensagem aparecer sempre, ou seja, não é preciso passar o rato por cima para a mensagem aparecer, ela está sempre presente. É possível fazer isso?

Estou a usar esta toolkip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
$(function() {
  $('input.age').mouseleave(function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }).tooltip({
    content: function() {
      return $(this).attr('title');
    }
  }).tooltip('open')
});

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input class="age" title="Hello <br/>My message">
```

Answer (score 0):

Retirado do site do jquery

```
var tooltips = $( "[title]" ).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "right+5 top-5"
      }
    });
      tooltips.tooltip( "open" );
```

[jQuery tooltip forms](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#forms)

Comment: como posso fazer isso sem usar o botão e aparecer sempre? estou a tentar usar mas perco algumas formatações, nomeadamente o html que tenho na mensagem. obrigado! @lazyFox